# How to modify the Announcement item detailed view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, list-view, app

I need to remove some columns from the view that show the details of an announcement list (the view that will be displayed when clicking on an announcement item) . The URL for the view looks as follow:-

```
http:// gvstg01:40708/sites/Intranet/Lists/ Group%20Announcement/DispForm.aspx?ID=63&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fgvstg01%3A40708%2Fsites%2FIntranet%2FSitePages%2FHome%2Easpx&ContentTypeId=
```

but I cannot see this view on the available views list, under the list setting. Can anyone advice?

**EDIT**

i add the following code inside DispForm.aspx:-

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideFields");
function findacontrol(FieldName) {
   var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("!");
   // get all comments
   for (var i=0;i < arr.length; i++ )
   {
      // now match the field name
      if (arr[i].innerHTML.indexOf(FieldName) > 0)
      {         return arr[i];      }
   }
}

function hideFields() {
   var control = findacontrol("Date");
   control.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none";

}
</script>
```

But still the Date field is displayed, not sure why the script was not able to hide the Date field ?

Answer (score 1):

John,

**FIRST METHOD (SHAREPOINT DESIGNER)**

It is not a view, it is a display form for the List.. You can do two things, if you want to hide some columns from just the Display Form (i.e. THIS VIEW).. You can edit the DispForm.aspx page using SharePoint Designer.. Navigate to List from SharePoint Designer -> Under Forms -> DispForm.aspx (Edit)

This will have a DataFormWebPart, from Ribbon you should be able to delete fields once you select this Web Part.

**SECOND METHOD (CODE)**

The other way, if you want to do it programmatically is to use [SPField.ShowInDisplayForm property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.showindisplayform.aspx).. You can set it to false to hide the field from Display Form

**OTHER**

If you want to hide your field from all the forms i.e. Display, Edit and New forms of a List.. You can turn on Management of content types from List settings and than once you have Item content type shown in List Setting -> Content Types -> Item.. You can click Item, it will display all the fields (your custom fields as well), click on a field and you have option saying, Hidden.. Check hidden to hide from Display Form, Edit Form and New Form!

Comment: thanks for the edit, i have followed your first approach, but when  i edited the  DispForm.aspx using SP designer, i can not see any reference to a column named "Date" in this form  ? can you advice please?

Comment: Do you have a column named "Date" in your list ?

Comment: yes it is the defualt Date column ,, that comes with the announcment App ?

Comment: You mean created and modified dates? these are contained in the footer of the display form?

Comment: sorry i got lost, this is a customize column which i have created, it is diffenrent from the created and modified. it is a date and time column i have created... and i can not find any reference for it inside the DispForm.aspx.

Comment: can you check my edit please.